# creating an image to be virtualized in OSX using Vmware fusion or Parallels

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualization

Is it possible to image a Windows machine and then create a virtual machine in either Fusion or Parallels using that image? I am giving up my old work laptop with windows 7 installed and i am moving the windows 7 license to my macbook pro to be virtualized. I was just going to do install anyway but this capability would make my decision to go with Fusion or Parallels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallels has [Parallels Transporter](http://www.parallels.com/products/pvc46/technology/transporter/) and  VMWare Fusion has a [migration assistant](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/migrate.html). I've used Transporter; it works fine. I've never used the VMWare option.